# Use HttpOpenRequest API to send a OPTIONS * (asterisk) request

Tags: winapi, wininet

I can use the wininet function HttpOpenRequest and specify the lpszVerb argument as "OPTIONS" and the lpszObjectName as "/" to perform a

```
OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
```

request to a web server.

However, I'd prefer this syntax (to query the general servers options):

```
OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1
```

But when I specify the lpszObjectName argument as "*" the query will be this:

```
OPTIONS /* HTTP/1.1
```

Is there a way to make this function send the asterisk only, without prepending a slash?

Thanks